# Error on goal package with vaadin-maven-plugin with gitlab CI

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, vaadin, gitlab-ci

I'm using Vaadin and the vaadin-maven-plugin to build a project with front files. 
When I am running the goal locally I have no errors and the project builds successfully:

```
[INFO] Installed Yarn locally.
[INFO] Running 'yarn install' in /home/kaa/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target
[INFO] yarn install v1.6.0
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[ERROR] warning babel-preset-env > browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
[INFO] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[INFO] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[ERROR] warning "polymer-build > polymer-project-config@3.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "polymer-analyzer@^3.0.0-pre.17 || ^3.0.0".
[INFO] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[INFO] success Saved lockfile.
[INFO] Done in 7.12s.
[INFO] Processing frontend files from '/home/kaa/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target/frontend'
[INFO] Running 'gulp build_es6' in /home/kaa/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target
[INFO] [12:28:51] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target/gulpfile.js
[INFO] [12:28:51] Starting 'build_es6'...
[INFO] Deleting /home/kaa/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target/classes/META-INF/resources/frontend-es6 directory...
[INFO] [12:28:51] Finished 'build_es6' after 5.17 ms
[INFO] Starting to process frontend files.
[INFO] Will minify frontend files.
[INFO] Will bundle frontend files.
[INFO] Will hash bundle file names.
[INFO] Will copy files to target directory '/home/kaa/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target/classes/META-INF/resources/frontend-es6'.
[INFO] Starting operations stated above, this might take a while.
[INFO] Writing bundle manifest to '/home/kaa/Documents/Projects/limitmanager.front/target/classes/META-INF/resources/frontend-es6/vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json'
```

But, running on gitlab CI causes an error:

```
 Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bcsbankms/limitmanager.front/target/node/node" (in directory "/bcsbankms/limitmanager.front/target"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Part of the log:

```
57389 [ERROR] warning "polymer-build > polymer-project-config@3.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "polymer-analyzer@^3.0.0-pre.17 || ^3.0.0".
59986 [INFO] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
60052 [INFO] success Saved lockfile.
60055 [INFO] Done in 34.04s.
60071 [INFO] Processing frontend files from '/bcsbankms/limitmanager.front/target/frontend'
60086 [INFO] Running 'gulp build_es6' in /bcsbankms/limitmanager.front/target
60091 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
60091 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
60091 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
60093 [INFO] Total time: 59.119 s
60093 [INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-05T05:54:08Z
60094 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
60094 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production (default) on project ru.bcs.bank.ms.limitmanager.front: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production failed: Transpilation with gulp has failed: 'gulp build_es6' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bcsbankms/limitmanager.front/target/node/node" (in directory "/bcsbankms/limitmanager.front/target"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production (default) on project ru.bcs.bank.ms.limitmanager.front: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:11.0.0:package-for-production failed: Transpilation with gulp has failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/issues/93).

As far as i know, you can ignore it.